# ng-click works only once inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and struggling with `ng-click` inside `ng-repeat`. For some reason, it only fires once, and the following clicks throw the following error:

[image]

Controller:

```
(function ( window, angular ) {
    'use strict'

    var LeadsController = function ( $scope, $http, $cookies, breadcrumbFactory ) {
        $scope.leads = []
        $scope.activeLead = undefined
        $scope.breadcrumb = breadcrumbFactory

        $scope.getLeads = function () {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/admin/leads'
            })

            .success( function getLeadsSuccess ( data ) {
                $scope.leads = data.data
                $scope.activeLead = $scope.leads[0]
            })

            .error( function getLeadsError ( err ) {
                console.error( err )
            })
        }

        $scope.activateLead = function () {
            $scope.activeLead = this.lead
        }

        $scope.getLeads()
    }

    angular
        .module( 'app' )
        .controller( 'LeadsController', [
            '$scope',
            '$http',
            '$cookies',
            'breadcrumbFactory',
            LeadsController
        ])
})( window, angular );
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="list list--dual-line" id="leads-list">
    <li ng-repeat="lead in leads">
        <a ng-click="activateLead()">
            <p>{{ lead.firstName }} {{ lead.lastName }}</p>
            <small>{{ lead.email }}</small>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to use $parent.activateLead( $event ) if instead you pass the current lead like activateLead( $event, lead ).  Better yet, you could just pass lead like activateLead( lead ) since unless there's something else going on that would make you need to call $event.preventDefault() from your func.

Comment: @jbrown thanks for pointing out that `$parent` isn't required. That said, the function is only being called on the first click. The following clicks get an error.

Comment: Do all your leads also have functions name `lead`?  If not, this line `$scope.activateLead = lead` will overwrite the ng-click handler to a non-function.

Comment: Really, there's probably an easier way to refactor your ng-repeat and the click even interaction.  If you describe what you're trying to accomplish at a higher level (and maybe include some detail of what a lead looks like), that could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code you're replacing the function activateLead with the lead that's being clicked:

```
$scope.activateLead = function ( lead ) {
        debugger
        $scope.activateLead = lead
    }
```

Not sure what this line is supposed to do but this is the problem:

```
$scope.activateLead = lead
```

Comment: Passing `lead` actually does not work. But calling `this.lead` works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Verify function:

```
$scope.activateLead = function ( lead ) {
    debugger
    $scope.activeLead = lead
}
```

the variable name is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
  $scope.activateLead = function(lead) {
    $scope.activeLead = lead;
  };
```

HTML:

```
  <ul class="list list--dual-line" id="leads-list">
    <li ng-repeat="lead in leads">
      <a ng-click="activateLead(lead)">
        <p>{{ lead.firstName }} {{ lead.lastName }}</p>
        <small>{{ lead.email }}</small>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```